# Why is MYSQL_DATABASE env var being ignored by MySQL docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "mysql"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "mydb"
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    volumes:
      - ./supplied/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

When I run 'docker-compose up' It see this :

> Recreating db ... done
>   Attaching to db

If I check the available databases I see:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| db                 |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```

Why is it ignoring my MYSQL_DATABASE environment variable?

I'm running on windows 10.

EDIT :

This looks like some sort of caching issue.  I changed the service name and container_name in the docker-compose file and it started working...

Comment: How do you know it ignored your environment variable?

Comment: @RedCricket: Because the MYSQL_DATABASE is meant to set the database name, but the database created is named 'db' instead of 'mydb'.  However it turns out this is a caching issue.  Running with docker-compose up --force-recreate just loads up the previously created image.  If I change the service and container name I get what I want, but I now need a way to avoid this caching problem.

Comment: Are you running `mysql > show databases;` inside Docker container?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo: Yes, I'm doing a docker exec to get into the running mysql container.

Comment: did you solve this issue? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: It's been a while and I don't remember, but it's probably worth docker rm and/or docker rmi the previously created container.

Answer (score 4):

from https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/180:

> Important to note that the image entrypoint script will never make
> changes to an existing database. If you mount an existing data
> directory into var/lib/mysql, options like MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD will
> have no effect

My issue was that the volume already existed. When I removed the volume with `docker-compose down -v`
When I brought it up, it would created the database.

Comment: Same problem here and rebuilding containers and images didn't help

Comment: this is exactly my case, delete the volume manually or use the option above.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`--force-recreate`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) flag:

```
--force-recreate           Recreate containers even if their configuration
                           and image haven't changed.
```

Comment: I tried it. --force-recreate does not resolve the problem.